# Simplifying radicals for limit leads to extra minus symbol

Tags: calculus, limits

I am asked to calculate the limits of $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ for $x\to\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$

When I simplify the radical for $x\to\infty$, I generate:

$\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}}$, after which I can use l'hopital the two parts because they are $\infty / \infty$.

I do lim lim $x\to-\infty$ in similar fashion, but here an extra minus appears in the simplying radicals step that I can't quite place. I never actually use that $x\to -\infty$, so I'm kind of lost how that gets there?

Comment: The problem with you method is that your equation holds only for $x \ge 0$, since $\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 = |x|$.

Comment: After getting one single square root why in the world would you want to use l'Hospital?

Answer (score 3):

We can assume $\;x<0\;$ when $\;x\to-\infty\;$ :

$$\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=-\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=-\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}-1$$

The gist here is that

$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=\begin{cases}x&,\;\;x\ge 0\\{}\\-x&,\;\;x<0\end{cases}$$

which in fact is present in a little hidden form in the last line of Babak's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you don't need of using L'Hopital's rule here. Note that when $x\to\pm\infty$: $$1+x^2\sim x^2$$ and so $$\sqrt{1+x^2}\sim |x|$$

Comment: Nice, though I think the OP had a more specific doubt about the case when $\;x\to -\infty\;$ +1

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes, I really meant what you posted in details, Don. Thanks. +)